# Have a Moto g play believe 4th gen...

Tags: sd-card

And when I go into storage my SD card doesn't show. I removed and put back in then it shows for a bit then randomly says ejecting SD card... Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Bad card or bad device... I suggest getting a new, quality SD card and test it and if a new card does the same thing contact Moto customer care.

Comment: I had the same problem with several SD cards. I t seems the card reader is damaged